# Laravel argument string given instead of model?

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a bit of a strange problem in my Laravel application. I need to access my `StatusPage` model that's scoped to an account. My model uses a UUID instead of int for the primary key, when I use `$statusPage` as my variable I get:

> App\Http\Controllers\Account\StatusPageController::show(): Argument #3 ($statusPage) must be of type App\Models\StatusPage, string given

What am I missing here?

```php
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 */
public function show(User $user, StatusPage $statusPage, Request $request)
{
    // if ($request->boolean('with_incident_updates')) {
    //     $statusPage = $statusPage->load('incident_updates');
    // }

    return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
        'user' => $user,
        'statuspage' => $statusPage
    ]);
}
```

My routes

```php
Route::apiResources([
    'account.status-pages' => StatusPageController::class,
]);
```

#### additional context

[image]

[image]

and called link:

- GET - http://localhost:8000/api/account/1/status-pages/f062f572-7273-4fba-a61c-17a3039e5d34

My `StatusPage` model does have incrementing off:

```php
/**
 * Indicates if the model's ID is auto-incrementing.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $incrementing = false;
```

I've also tried using `$status_page`, same error.

Comment: how do you call your route ? or how do the route look like if you type the command `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: I've updated my post with additional context. Please see

Comment: try changing `$statusPage` to `$status_page` ?

Comment: That gives me the same error: `Argument #2 ($status_page) must be of type App\\Models\\StatusPage, string given` I'll add to post

Comment: To use route model binding the variable name in the route and the controller should match. Here you seem to be calling the $user variable in the controller with account in the route, and $statusPage in the controller with status_page in the route neither of these will work. Match $user with {user} and $statusPage with {statusPage}. Incidentally you don’t appear to use the $user variable in the controller code so why include it?

Comment: The problem is that you arre sending the 'uuid' string instead of the model.

Comment: @niallD I'm not totally sure of the accuracy of what you're describing here. I've updated my original post, see that `$user` does indeed pull out the user,`$statusPage` is being read as a string, but `$user` technically is as well because as described, they're coming in from the request. I have Laravel telescope installed, and with my current structure the query is working, but laravel is throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

The solution here in the end was really simply. All I needed to do is replace `$user` with `$account`, that's it.

```php
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 */
public function show(User $account, StatusPage $statusPage, Request $request)
{
    // if ($request->boolean('with_incident_updates')) {
    //     $statusPage = $statusPage->load('incident_updates');
    // }

    return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
        'user' => $account,
        'statuspage' => $statusPage
    ]);
}
```

- `$statusPage` works as is
- `$account` now works